# What I am doing wrong while finding the blotted part here?

Tags: java, algorithm

Problem Description: 
Jimmy is a hard-working pupil in his second year at primary school. Recently he decided to convert all his notes into an electronic version. Sadly, he found that his math notes were full of ink blots.

He scanned the notes and sent them through his own OCR package (yes, he coded it all by himself at the age of 8). The OCR package replaced all ink blots by the string "machula".

Problem specification

You are given Jimmy's notes, processed by the OCR. They contain simple math exercises, which were used to practice addition on positive integers. Your task is to recover the damaged part of the notes.

Input specification

The first line of the input file contains an integer T specifying the number of test cases. Each test case is preceded by a blank line.

Each test case consists of exactly one line. The line represents an equation of the form "number + number = number", where each number is a positive integer. One part of the equation will be replaced by the string "machula". The string always covers a contiguous non-empty sequence of digits, possibly even an entire number. You may assume that for each equation in the input there will be exactly one way to fill in the missing digits.

Output specification

For each test case, the output shall contain one line of the form "number + number = number". The line must represent the equation from that test case with all missing digits filled in.

Example

Input:

```
3

23 + 47 = machula

3247 + 5machula2 = 3749

machula13 + 75425 = 77038
```

Output:

```
 23 + 47 = 70

 3247 + 502 = 3749

 1613 + 75425 = 77038
```

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        while(t-->0)
        {
            br.readLine();
            String s = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("");
            int eq_n=s.indexOf("=");
            int plus_n=s.indexOf("+");
            int machula=s.indexOf("machula");

            if(machula>eq_n)
            {
                int num1=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, plus_n-1));
                int num2=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(plus_n+2, eq_n-1));
                out.write(String.valueOf(num1)+" + "+String.valueOf(num2)+" = "+String.valueOf(num1+num2)+"\n");
            }
            else
            {
                if(machula>plus_n)
                {
                    int num1=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, plus_n-1));
                    int num2=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(eq_n+2));
                    out.write(String.valueOf(num1)+" + "+String.valueOf(num2-num1)+" = "+String.valueOf(num2)+"\n");
                }
                else if(machula<plus_n)
                {
                    int num1=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(plus_n+2, eq_n-1));
                    int num2=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(eq_n+2));
                    out.write(String.valueOf(num2-num1)+" + "+String.valueOf(num1)+" = "+String.valueOf(num2)+"\n");
                }
            }
        }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
    }
}
```

Problem Link: http://www.spoj.com/problems/ABSYS/

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code and it prints the specified output for me. The only thing I did to your code is make it read from a file instead of reading from System.in.

So instead of

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Do this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:/machula.txt")));
```

Of course make sure that C:/machula.txt exists and contains your input values. Also I removed the System.out.prinln("") that was causing blank lines to be printed in the output.

Comment: But I do need to use a system.in as I need to submit te solution to an online judge where I cannot read a file from my system but rather give test cases from the terminal.
But yes removing that extra print statement helped me in getting accepting the code. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I just ran it and entered the values from the command line and it worked like a charm. What problem are you having?